# Address-Override Prefix in 64-bit mode

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel, virtual-address-space, amd-processor

In 64-bit mode, the default address size is 64 bits. If the address-size override prefix (67h) is present, the address size is 32-bits.

I'm aware of the fact that canonical 64-bit addresses have bits 63 through the most significant implemented bit either all 0s or all 1s. Is the 32-bit address (obtained by prefixing 67h to an instruction in 64-bit mode) required to be in canonical form? If yes, how is this canonical form defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Canonical addresses are formed by sign-extending the significant part (the lower 48 bits) of a virtual address; the most significant bit is treated as the sign.

Speculating on this now (not willing to look it up - but that's also not necessary to answer your question) - there's two conceivable behaviours for 32bit addresses in 64bit mode:

1. The CPU treats it like the use of a 32bit register/operand, i.e. zero-extend to 64bit / implicitly treat the high 32bit as zeroes
   In this case, *any* 32bit address is canonical because any 64bit address `0x00000000xxxxxxxx` is canonical.
2. The CPU treats it as "32bit significant" and sign-extends to 64bit from the most significant bit of the 32bit address
   In this case as well, *any* 32bit address is canonical, because then the 32bit range would map from `0xffffffff80000000` ... `0x000000007fffffff` - again, all of which are canonical.

Since the result (32bit addresses always implicitly being of canonical form) is the same, it doesn't matter what the CPU actually does - 32bit addresses are canonical, period.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Also, I went through the Intel Manuals more carefully and in Vol 1, p3-12, I found that the 32-bit address is zero-extended to form a 64-bit address. Just put it here in case some one wondered about effective address calculations.